# Angular Error when building using `ng build --prod' command

Tags: angular

I am building my angular application using ng build --prod command but it is giving me this error. It was working fine with ng --serve though. I am not able to understand what problem is.

**ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css from C:/Users/soura/Desktop/Bicyle rent/frontend/src/app/parts/navigation/navigation.component.html**

Comment: You should add bootstrap.min.css to your assets folder. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/ Actually `npm install` should do that for you. Check you package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng build** instead,
because ng build command ,now uses the **production configuration** by default.
*You no longer need to pass the --prod option to the command.*
Since the latest version of angular, the old commands are deprecated such as --prod.